# Error using ethers.js and Pancakeswap router (UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION: cannot override)

Tags: nodejs, bsc, pancakeswap, npm

I am very noob on ethers and can't fix this error.
The code initially finds a new pair with PairCreated and exchanges it for WBNB with the router. However, when I run the code I get an override error like this. The code lists new pairs without any problems, but does not trade.

```
Error: cannot override "_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toString","toHexString","toJSON" (operation="overrides", overrides=["_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toString","toHexString","toJSON"], code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.0.12)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:180:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:189:20)
    at C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:237:32
    at step (C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\vmen\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'cannot override "_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toString","toHexString","toJSON"',"_hex","_isBigNumber","fromTwos","toTwos","abs","add","sub","div","mul","mod","pow","and","or","xor","mask","shl","shr","eq","lt","lte","gt","gte","isNegative","isZero","toNumber","toString","toHexString","toJSON"',
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'overrides',
  overrides: [
    '_hex',     '_isBigNumber', 'fromTwos',
    'toTwos',   'abs',          'add',
    'sub',      'div',          'mul',
    'mod',      'pow',          'and',
    'or',       'xor',          'mask',
    'shl',      'shr',          'eq',
    'lt',       'lte',          'gt',
    'gte',      'isNegative',   'isZero',
    'toNumber', 'toString',     'toHexString',
    'toJSON'
  ]
```

Here is my code

```
var path = require('path')
var filename = path.dirname('config.json') + '\\config.json'

const ethers = require('ethers');
const json = require(filename)

const addresses = {
  WBNB: json.data.WBNB,
  factory: json.data.factory,
  router: json.data.router,
  recipient: json.data.recipient
}

const privateKey = 'goes here'; 

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('private')
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
const account = wallet.connect(provider);
const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.factory,
  ['event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)'],
  account
)
const router = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.router,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
  ],
  account
)

const wbnb = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.WBNB,
  [
    'function approve(address spender) public returns(bool)',
  ],
  account
)

const init = async () => {
  const tx = await wbnb.approve(
    router.address,
    ethers.constants.MaxUint256
  )
  const receipt = await tx.wait()
  console.log('Transaction receipt')
  console.log(receipt)
}

factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => {
  console.log(`
    New pair detected
    =================
    token0: ${token0}
    token1: ${token1}
    pairAddress: ${pairAddress}
  `);

  let tokenIn, tokenOut;
  if(token0 === addresses.WBNB) {
    tokenIn = token0
    tokenOut = token1
  }

  if(token1 == addresses.WBNB) {
    tokenIn = token1 
    tokenOut = token0
  }

  if(typeof tokenIn === 'undefined') {
    return
  }

  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.001', 'ether');
  const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenIn, tokenOut])
  const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10))
  console.log(`
    Buying new token
    =================
    tokenIn: ${amountIn.toString()} ${tokenIn} (WBNB)
    tokenOut: ${amounOutMin.toString()} ${tokenOut}
  `)
  const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    [tokenIn, tokenOut],
    addresses.recipient,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, // 10 minutes
    {
        gasPrice: 500000000,
        gasLimit: 100000
    }
  )
  const receipt = await tx.wait()
  console.log('Transaction receipt')
  console.log(receipt)
})

init().catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

Comment: Do you know which line causes the problem? Also deadline parameter from `swapExactTokensForTokens` should be a unix time stamp (seconds from 1970-01-01) and javascript `Date.now()` returns milliseconds.